# Trying to find the value of a cell in column b of the last row in sheet1

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find the value of the last cell in column b of sheet1. This value will change weekly. I then want to take that value and find it in sheet2. Then I want to copy and paste all data below this found value to sheet3. I can't get past the first part with the following code:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim rangefound As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set cell = Range("B:B").Find("rangefound")
rangefound = lastRow = Cells(lastRow, 2).Value
```

I've been struggling with the syntax for a month and really don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Sub test()

Dim cell As Range
Dim rangefound As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

rangefound = Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value

Set cell = Sheet2.Range("B:B").Find(rangefound)

MsgBox "The value was found in Sheet2!" & cell.Address

End Sub
```

The issues with your code were

- using `rangefound` before it had a value, i.e. the order of the commands
- using `"rangefound"` as a text instead of the variable
- wrong syntax to assign a value to `rangefound`
- not qualifying which sheet should be searched

Edit: To extend the code to copy the data below the found value to another sheet, use Offset to reference one row below. There are many different ways to do this, so using Offset is just one option.

Here is the complete code

```
Sub test()

Dim mycell As Range, RangeToCopy As Range
Dim rangefound As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

rangefound = Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value

' this is the cell with the found value
Set mycell = Sheet2.Range("B:B").Find(rangefound)

' now find the last row in Sheet2. We can use lastRow again,
' since it is no longer needed elsewhere

lastRow = Sheet2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' set the range to copy to start one cell below rangefound
' to the end of the data in column B
Set RangeToCopy = Sheet2.Range(cell.Offset(1, 0), Sheet2.Cells(lastRow, "B"))
' copy the range and paste into Sheet3, starting at A1
RangeToCopy.Copy Sheet3.Range("A1")


End Sub
```

Note: I changed the variable name from "cell" to "mycell". It's better to use variable names that cannot be mistaken for Excel artifacts.

Another edit: If you need to paste into the next free row in Sheet3, use the techniques already established.

```
[...]
Set RangeToCopy = Sheet2.Range(cell.Offset(1, 0), Sheet2.Cells(lastRow, "B"))
    
    ' get the next available row in Sheet3
    lastRow = Sheet3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ' copy and paste
    RangeToCopy.Copy Sheet3.Range("A" & lastRow)
[...]
```

Note that I'm using the same variable for three different purposes. If that is too confusing, create three distinct variables instead.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn. That pretty much worked. I received a run time error 6 so I changed rangefound as integer to Long and that worked. Greatly appreciate your help. I don't want to push my luck but I'm not sure how to code the second part of my project: "Then I want to copy and paste all data below this found value to sheet3". I'm not sure how to proceed with selecting data to copy below a found variable...

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I changed one spot in the code and it works. I changed "cell to mycell" in this line: Set RangeToCopy = Sheet10.Range(mycell.Offset(1, 0), Sheet10.Cells(LastRow2, "B")). I would also like to copy and paste the selected range to the bottom of sheet3 instead of A1 and include all columns instead of just column "B". I have columns A to J. I tried: RangeToCopy.Copy Sheet3.Range(lastRow, "A:J") but it doesn't work...

Comment: Well, you already have code that can find the last row in a sheet. Use code like this to find the last row in Sheet3 and assign it to a variable. Then use that variable as the row number for the paste destination instead of A1. You just need to write a few more lines of code, but every technique you need is already in the code, so try to understand what the code does, so you can apply the technique.

Comment: That's fine. I've tried what you've mentioned but my syntax and variable is obviously wrong. I'll try again. It's close but very frustrating. I'll keep guessing until I get it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've updated the code as you suggested and it works. The last thing I'm trying to change is the copy and paste. Instead of copying and pasting column "b" I need to copy and paste columns A to J. I can't figure out the syntax for this after several hours of research.

Comment: Please don't edit my answer. You are tacking on more questions. Please accept the answer as described in the [tour]. Then feel free to ask additional questions, but start new questions, don't drag this one out forever.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how to use this system. The tour is confusing as well. I've edited the offset and it's working.